# Android: How to combine Swipe gesture with Longpress in a item on listView

Tags: android, android-listview, gesture, swipe, long-press

I have a listview which I personalized and I added `setOnItemLongClickListener()` which worked well. Then I decided to implement a gesture `listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener())` which also works well. I copied the `OnSwipetouchListener` class from another post.

The thing is that when I added the swipe listener the longPress didn't work anymore. I guess it's because the swipe listener takes the longpress actions for itself and doesn't allow longPress to do anything.

What I want to do:

The swipe listener gets everything below 2 seconds, after that everything goes to longpress. So I can still change the listview content by a swipe gesture and I can also create functions for each listitem.

My code:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
        //super.onTouch(v, event);
         return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
...methods...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the onDown method. Right now that is always returning true and preventing the longPress from being handled.